# What is wrong with this argument that $ \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} $ is not cancellative in positive characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I have a question about a result of Abyankar, Heinzer, and Eakin, and a similar result in Russell.  One of the results in the first paper is that if $ Y $ is a variety such that $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} \times Y \cong \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} $ then $ Y \cong \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $.  I found an argument that suggests that this is not the case and so I was wondering if anyone could help me find what is wrong.

Let $ k $ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $ p>0 $.  Let $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $ act on $ \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} $ as follows:
\begin{align*}
    x_{1} & \mapsto x_{1}+t^{p} \\
    x_{2} & \mapsto x_{2}-t^{p^{2}}+t.
\end{align*}

The first part of this argument is the following claim:

If $ g(X) $ is the polynomial below:
\begin{equation} 
    g(X) = x_{1}^{p}+x_{2},
\end{equation}
and $ f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X) $ are the following polynomials:
\begin{align}
    f_{1}(X) &= x_{1}-g(X)^{p}, \\
    f_{2}(X) &= x_{2}+g(X)^{p^{2}}-g(X),
\end{align}
then $ \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} \cong \mathbb{G}_{a} \times \operatorname{Spec}(k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X)]) $.

Here is the p``r''oof of this claim:

If $ A $ is the ring $ k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X),t] $ then let $ \Phi $ be the following ring homomorphism from $ A $ to $ k[x_{1},x_{2}] $:
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(f_{1}(X)) &= f_{1}(X) \\
    \Phi(f_{2}(X)) &= f_{2}(X) \\
    \Phi(t) &= g(X).
\end{align*}
If $ \Psi: k[x_{1},x_{2}] \to A $ is the following ring homomorphism:
\begin{align*}
    \Psi(x_{1}) &= f_{1}(X)+t^{p} \\
    \Psi(x_{2}) &= f_{2}(X)-t^{p^{2}}+t,
\end{align*}
then the following identities show that $ \Psi $ is an inverse of $ \Phi $:
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(\Psi(x_{1})) &= \Phi(f_{1}(X)+t^{p}) \\
    &= f_{1}(X)+g(X)^{p} \\
    &= x_{1}-g(X)^{p}+g(X)^{p} \\
    &= x_{1} \\
    \Phi(\Psi(x_{2})) &= \Phi(f_{2}(X)-t^{p^{2}}+t) \\
    &= f_{2}(X)-g(X)^{p^{2}}+g(X) \\
    &= x_{2}+g(X)^{p^{2}}-g(X)-g(X)^{p^{2}}+g(X)  \\
    &= x_{2} \\
    \Psi(\Phi(f_{1}(X))) &= \Psi(f_{1}(X)) \\
    &= f_{1}(X) \\
    \Psi(\Phi(f_{2}(X))) &= \Psi(f_{2}(X)) \\
    &= f_{2}(X) \\
    \Psi(\Phi(t)) &= \Psi(g(X)) \\
    &= \Psi(x_{1}^{p}+x_{2}) \\
    &= f_{1}(X)^{p}+t^{p^{2}}+f_{2}(X)-t^{p^{2}}+t \\
    &= f_{1}(X)^{p}+f_{2}(X)+t \\
    &= x_{1}^{p}-g(X)^{p^{2}}+x_{2}+g(X)^{p^{2}}-g(X)+t \\
    &= x_{1}^{p}+x_{2}-g(X)+t \\
    &= g(X)-g(X)+t \\
    &=t.
\end{align*}
Therefore $ k[x_{1},x_{2}] \cong k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X),t] $.

The second part of the argument is the following claim.

If $ g(X), f_{1}(X) $ and $ f_{2}(X) $ are the following polynomials:
\begin{align*}
    g(X) &= x_{1}^{p}+x_{2}, \\
    f_{1}(X) &= x_{1}-g(X)^{p}, \\
    f_{2}(X) &= x_{2}+g(X)^{p^{2}}-g(X),
\end{align*}
then $ k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X)] \cong k[y_{1},y_{2}]/\langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle $.

Here is the p``r''oof of this claim:

The following identities show that $ f_{1}(X)^{p}+f_{2}(X) $ is equal to zero:
\begin{align*}
    f_{1}(X)^{p}+f_{2}(X) &= x_{1}^{p}-g(X)^{p^{2}}+x_{2}+g(X)^{p^{2}}-g(X) \\
    &= x_{1}^{p}+x_{2}-g(X) \\
    &= g(X)-g(X) \\
    &=0.
\end{align*}
If $ \Phi: k[y_{1},y_{2}] \to k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X)] $ by sending $ y_{i} $ to $ f_{i}(X) $, then the kernel of $ \Phi $ contains $ \langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle $.  Since $ \mathbb{G}_{a} \times \operatorname{Spec}(k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X)]) \cong \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} $, the ring $ k[f_{1}(X),f_{2}(X)] $ must have dimension at least one.  This means that the height of $ \ker(\Phi) $ must be less than two.  The ring $ k[y_{1},y_{2}] $ is a UFD, and so the kernel of $ \Phi $ is principal.  Therefore, the kernel of $ \Phi $ is exactly $ \langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle $.

This now seems to show that $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[y_{1},y_{2}]/\langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle) \times \mathbb{G}_{a} \cong \mathbb{A}^{2}_{k} $, but the variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[y_{1},y_{2}]/\langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle) $ is not isomorphic to $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $ as its field of fractions is a purely inseparable extension of degree $ p $ of the field of fractions of $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k} $.

If anyone sees the mistake, I would appreciate it if they would let me know.

*Abhyankar, Shreeram S.; Heinzer, William; Eakin, Paul*, [**On the uniqueness of the coefficient ring in a polynomial ring**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(72)90134-2), J. Algebra 23, 310-342 (1972). [ZBL0255.13008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0255.13008).

*Russell, Peter*, [**On affine-ruled rational surfaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01450704), Math. Ann. 255, 287-302 (1981). [ZBL0438.14024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0438.14024).

Comment: "p``r''oof"?‍${}$

Comment: The $k$-algebra $k[y_1,y_2]/\langle y_1^p + y_2 \rangle$ is isomorphic as a $k$-algebra to the polynomial ring $k[y]$ via the homomorphism that sends $y_1$ to $y$ and that sends $y_2$ to $-y^p$.

Comment: Thank you Jason!!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I only have one more question about this.  If we changed the action to:
\begin{align*}
x_{1} & \mapsto x_{1}+t^{p^{2}}-t^{p}+t \\
x_{2} & \mapsto x_{2}+t^{p},
\end{align*}
then I believe the argument changes $ g(X) $ to $ x_{1}^{p}+x_{1}-x_{2}^{p^{2}} $, $ f_{1}(X) $ to $ x_{1}-g(X)^{p^{2}}+g(X)^{p}-g(X) $ and $ f_{2}(X) $ to $ x_{2}-g(X)^{p} $.  In this case, I believe that the ring $ k[y_{1},y_{2}]/\langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{2} \rangle $ changes to $ k[y_{1},y_{2}]/\langle y_{1}^{p}+y_{1}-y_{2}^{p^{2}} \rangle $.  Is there a similar isomorphism in this case?  Thank you.